# Python: Two Input Sources for Global Variables

Tags: python, input, global-variables, config

```
#program_1
import Config_User

country_code = Config_User.country_code
state_code = Config_User.state_code

<main code....>


#program_2
country_code = input("Enter Country Code:  ")
state_code = input("Enter State Code:  ")

<insert code here that runs program_1, and takes variables country_code and 
 state_code from user_input from program_2 as opposed to variables in Config_User>
```

I'm looking for some way around the problem above. In program_1, users enter in variables in a config file, and then those get pulled as global variables. However, if users choose to run program_2, the program asks them for input for country_code and state_code, and program_1 runs with variables specified by users from program_2 and not variables in config file.

What this boils down to is this: can I have two different sources for global variables? If users run program_1, variables come from config file. If users run program_2, variables come from user input.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about sharing the `Global Variable` across multiple mobdule, however how about using `static variable`?

**config_user.py**

```
class ConfigUser(object):
    country_code = "USA000"
    state_code = "CAL0001"
```

from config_user import ConfigUser

**prog1.py**

```
def main():
    print ConfigUser.country_code
    print ConfigUser.state_code


if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

**prog2.py**

```
from config_user import ConfigUser
from prog1 import main


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ConfigUser.country_code = raw_input("Enter Country Code:  ")
    ConfigUser.state_code = raw_input("Enter State Code:  ")
    main()
```

Comment: This actually did not fix the problem. This still makes two separate programs, and I only want one. But I did find a way around this problem on my own. Thanks.